# Discord.net better Help command

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I've got a basic help command which takes the summery and remarks and it works great now. But it looks chunky when every command is together and every other line the text is darker, is there a way to fix both these issues. Here's the code:

```
public class HelpHandler : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    private readonly CommandService _service;

    public HelpHandler(CommandService service)
    {
        Global.ConsoleLog("Started HelpHandler", ConsoleColor.Blue);

        _service = service;
    }

    [Command("help")]
    public async Task HelpAsync()
    {
        var builder = new EmbedBuilder()
        {
            Color = new Color(114, 137, 218),
            Description = "These are the commands you can use"
        };

        foreach (var module in _service.Modules)
        {
            string description = null;
            foreach (var cmd in module.Commands)
            {
                var result = await cmd.CheckPreconditionsAsync(Context);
                if (result.IsSuccess)
                    description += $"{Global.Preflix}{cmd.Aliases.First()}\n";
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description))
            {
                builder.AddField(x =>
                {
                    x.Name = module.Name;
                    x.Value = description;
                    x.IsInline = false;
                });
            }
        }

        await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build());
    }

}
```

[image: This image shows what it looks like. Clunky]

So to be more specific, is there a way to make it so that I can have different cards full of x amount of commands each and they you can scroll threw them with emoji reactions such as backwards and forwards? And is there a way to remove the horrible way it goes darker every other line of text for no apparent reason?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't get darker for no apparent reason, that's a single line `code block`. You are attaching the prefix to the front of the command alias, your prefix is **\`** which would mean you are actually inadvertently wrapping your alias in `{prefix}command \n{prefix}`.  That creates the code block. Everything else in the fist part of your question is a design issue an opinion based, find what works for you. As for the second part you can use **Discord.Addons.Interactive** and utilize its `Pagination` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you're totally right and I was being blind, and thank's for the information on how to make it look better

Comment: I can really recommend you this: https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/. When you are done creating your embed, click on "Generate Code" and select Discord.NET

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the link! That website looks really cool and I'll have a look now!